# javascript : to update all <td> element of <tr> in textbox when click on edit

Tags: javascript, html, jsobject

I am new to working in javascript, I am work Dom element and create a demo of crud with the table.

CRUDCODE:

```
     <html>
     <head>
     <style type="text/css">
        td {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
          }
    </style>
     </head>
     <input type="text" id="name"><br /><br />
     <input type="text" id="age"><br /><br />
     <input type="text" id="email"><br /><br />
     <input type="button" value="addNew" id="addNew"><br />
     <div id="output"></div>
     <script>
         let rows = [{
             name: "John",
             age: 20,
             email: "abc@gmail.com"
         }, {
            name: "Jack",
            age: 50,
            email: "pqr@gmail.com"
         }, {
            name: "Son",
            age: 45,
            email: "xyz@gmail.com"
         }];
          window.onload = building();
          let addNew = document.getElementById("addNew");
          addNew.onclick = function () {
          let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
          let age = document.getElementById("age").value;
          let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
          rows.push({
              name,
              age,
              email
          });
          console.log(rows);
          building();
          }
          function building() {
    let html = "<h1>student-Info</h1><table align='center'>";
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        html += '<tr id="id' + i + '"data-row="' + i + '">';
        html += "<td>" + rows[i].name + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + rows[i].age + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + rows[i].email + "</td>";
        html += "<td><a href='#' data-action='delete'>DELETE</a></td>";
        html += "<td><a href='#' data-action='edit'>Edit</a></td>";
        html += '</tr>';
    }
    html += "</table>";
    document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = html;
     let deleted = document.querySelectorAll('[data-action="delete"]');
    for (let i = 0; i < deleted.length; i++) {
        deleted[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            let ival = this.closest('[data-row]').getAttribute('data-row');
            let r = rows.splice(ival, 1);
            building();
           console.log(r);
        })
    }
    let edited = document.querySelectorAll('[data-action="edit"]');
    console.log(edited);
    for (let i = 0; i < edited.length; i++) {
        edited[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            let row = this.closest('[data-row]');
            let rid = row.getAttribute('data-row');
            let td = row.firstElementChild;
            let input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.value = td.innerText;
            td.innerHTML = "";
            td.appendChild(input);
            input.onblur = function () {
                td.removeChild(input);
                td.innerHTML = input.value;
                rows[rid] = input.value;
            }
        })
    }
}

     </script>
     </html>
```

I am getting all array data in loop "table" but when I click on edit I am not able to convert all "td" element
in "input" field,only first ""
the element will be converted.

Anybody have any idea please help to sort it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply the input field for firstElement in your code, but you need to get all the editable table field and update it like this

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        td {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<input type="text" id="name"><br /><br />
<input type="text" id="age"><br /><br />
<input type="text" id="email"><br /><br />
<input type="button" value="addNew" id="addNew"><br />
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
    let rows = [{
        name: "John",
        age: 20,
        email: "abc@gmail.com"
    }, {
        name: "Jack",
        age: 50,
        email: "pqr@gmail.com"
    }, {
        name: "Son",
        age: 45,
        email: "xyz@gmail.com"
    }];
    window.onload = building();
    let addNew = document.getElementById("addNew");
    addNew.onclick = function () {
        let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        let age = document.getElementById("age").value;
        let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        rows.push({
            name,
            age,
            email
        });
        building();
    }
    function building() {
        let html = "<h1>student-Info</h1><table align='center'>";
        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            html += '<tr id="id' + i + '"data-row="' + i + '">';
            html += "<td data-col='name'>" + rows[i].name + "</td>";
            html += "<td data-col='age'>" + rows[i].age + "</td>";
            html += "<td data-col='email'>" + rows[i].email + "</td>";
            html += "<td><a href='#' data-action='edit'>Edit</a></td>";
            html += "<td><a href='#' data-action='delete'>DELETE</a></td>";
            html += '</tr>';
        }
        html += "</table>";
        document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = html;
        let deleted = document.querySelectorAll('[data-action="delete"]');
        for (let i = 0; i < deleted.length; i++) {
            deleted[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.closest('[data-row]').parentNode.removeChild(this.closest('[data-row]'));
            })
        }
        let edited = document.querySelectorAll('[data-action="edit"]');
        for (let i = 0; i < edited.length; i++) {
            edited[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                let row = this.closest('[data-row]');
                let rid = row.getAttribute('data-row');
                const tdList  = row.querySelectorAll('td[data-col]');
                [...tdList].forEach(td => {
                    let input = document.createElement("input");
                    input.type = "text";
                    input.value = td.innerText;
                    td.innerHTML = "";
                    td.appendChild(input);
                    input.onblur = function () {
                        td.removeChild(input);
                        td.innerHTML = input.value;
                        rows[rid][td.dataset.col] = input.value;
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: you don't need to trigger the function again, just get the `tr` element and remove from the parent, i updated.

Comment: look your edit link also be text field converted, so that will not be converted as text only the filed (name, age, email) will convert into text, i don't have any issue in delete code

Comment: just update the css condtions like this `td:nth-last-child(n+3)` it will work

Comment: when you edited the value than after you will again add new collection insert, it will be added but the value of updated td will be undefined. , check it, please

Comment: you need to update the `row` value when blur, then only the changes will be reflected. just do the little debugging you will get the answer for your queries

Comment: i wil used rows[rid] = row.name; but no any output reflect

Comment: i will used input.value = this.closest('[data-row]').getAttribute('data-row');   for travesing so can u solve this.  i will used at end of line